# Toolbar with icons instead of text

Tags: tkinter, icons, toolbar

I just want to put icons instead of "Measure Distance", "Calculate Angles", .... How can I do it?

This is part of the code

```
    menubar = Menu(win)
    menubar.add_command(label = "Measure Distance", command = MeasureDistance)
    menubar.add_command(label = "Calculate Angles", command = CalculateAngles)
    menubar.add_command(label = "Create a Circle", command = CreateCircle)
    menubar.add_command(label = "Undo", command = Undo)
    menubar.add_command(label = "Save and Close", command = save_close)
    menubar.add_command(label = "Exit", command = win.destroy)  
    win.config(menu=menubar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit [this](http://zetcode.com/tkinter/menustoolbars/) page and scroll down a bit you may find what you have been searching for.
What you want will look something like this:

```py
menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.fileMenu = Menu(self.master, tearoff=0)
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fileMenu)

        toolbar = Frame(self.master, bd=1, relief=RAISED)

        self.img = Image.open("exit.png")
        eimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

        exitButton = Button(toolbar, image=eimg, relief=FLAT,
            command=self.quit)
        exitButton.image = eimg
        exitButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)
        self.pack()
```

You just have to change some variable names and that should be it.
It will look like this:
[image: Result. Image by zetcode.com]